# Ruby on Rails IF Statement Verification Check

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement

so I'm new to ruby on rails and I'm having a problem with this if statement, basically what I'm checking for is if the confirmation token in the sql database exists for the email address logging in. If it does kick back a message your email isn't verified. Once you click the link in the email, it deletes the token in the database. Then you can proceed to login. I cant get it working for the life of me. Everything else works but the verification check. Thank you for your help !!!

```html
 def authenticate(email, password)
   command = AuthenticateUser.call(email, password)
   user = User.find_by email:(email)
   confirmationtoken = 
   User.find_by_confirmation_token(params[:confirmation_token].to_s)
   if user.present? && confirmationtoken.present?
     render json: {error: 'Email not verified' }, status: :unauthorized
   elsif command.success?
     render json: {
       access_token: command.result,
       message: 'Login Successful'
     }
     else
       render json: { error: command.errors }, status: :unauthorized
     end
   end
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code as it is?

Comment: {
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJub25lIn0.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjo5NCwiZXhwIjoxNTI2NTcwOTI0fQ.",
    "message": "Login Successful"
}

Comment: Is this correct `user = User.find_by email:(email)`? I have not seen anything like that.

Comment: It returns a login access token and skips the verification process Message.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh it's the same as `user = User.find_by email: email` – the parentheses are superfluous (and somehow confusing).

Comment: Are you setting your confirmation token to anything?  Line 3 assigns it to nil, and then line 5 says if confirmation token, meaning the block under the if statement never gets executed, and instead goes to the elsif block

Comment: Maybe confirmationtoken = params[:confirmationtoken] ?

Comment: @Mark line 3 continues on line 4, it's actually `confirmationtoken = User. find_by_confirmation_token(...)`

Comment: It seems odd that you query the `users` table twice. Shouldn't you fetch the user by email and then check if `user.confirmation_token` is set? Besides, how do you call that action? What is the value for `params[:confirmation_token]`? (I suspect that it returns `nil`)

Comment: @mark tried it doesnt work.

Comment: I wanted to write it as one line statement and i failed horribly lol, like i said im new . How would you write this  . Basically if a user is logging in, and a confirmation_token is present in the table, kick back you arent verified.

Comment: @RayZuchowski the `confirmation_token` is stored in the `users` table as an attribute of that user, is that correct?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: Stefan and Evan thank you !!!! Both worked !!!

Comment: Then accept one of them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check whether the user's `confirmation_token` attribute is set:

```
user = User.find_by(email: email)
if user && user.confirmation_token.present?
  # ...
elsif command.success?
  # ...
else
  # ...
end
```

`user.confirmation_token.present?` can be shortened to `user.confirmation_token?`

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help clean up your logic since theres no need to do a user lookup twice. And looking up the user and using the object could cause security concern .. let AuthenticateUser find the user and get success if they're in the system. When you send an email off just build a button in the email with a link to an endpoint that will verify the email and set the confirmation token to nil.

```html
 def authenticate(email, password)
   command = AuthenticateUser.call(email, password)
   has_confirmation_token = 
   User.find_by_confirmation_token(params[:confirmation_token]).present?
   if !has_confirmation_token && !command.success?
     render json: {error: 'Email not verified' }, status: :unauthorized
   elsif command && command.success?
     render json: {
       access_token: command.result,
       message: 'Login Successful'
     }
     else
       render json: { error: command.errors }, status: :unauthorized
     end
   end
```